# sed: add semicolon after each sentence

Tags: sed

I'm using this grep in order to extract "SQL " sentences from my log file:

```
grep -oPzZ ' SQL "\K[^"]+' log.log
```

After that, I need to format it adding `;` at the end of each detected sql sentence:

```
grep -oPzZ ' SQL "\K[^"]+' log.log | sed -E '$s/$/\n/; s/\x0/;/; s/^[[:blank:]]+//'
```

Nevertheless, it seems to not working at all. I mean, I'm getting:

```
alter table HFJ_RES_LINK modify ( SRC_PATH varchar2(200) );create index IDX_VALUESET_EXP_STATUS on TRM_VALUESET(EXPANSION_STATUS)drop index IDX_VALUESET_EXP_STATUS
```

As you can see, first `;` is added after first detected sql sentence, later is not added.

`log.log` is similar to:

```
3_6_0.20180929.1: SQL "alter table HFJ_RES_LINK modify ( SRC_PATH varchar2(200) )" returned 0
4_0_0.20190722.37: SQL "create index IDX_VALUESET_EXP_STATUS on TRM_VALUESET(EXPANSION_STATUS)" returned 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/\x00/;\n/g; s/^[[:blank:]]+//'`, it [should work](https://ideone.com/vYlIQ5).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `awk` here as you can combine both `grep` and `sed` operations into a single command. Consider this `gnu awk` solution:

```sh
awk -v RS='SQL "[^"]+"' 'RT {gsub(/^SQL "|"|\n/, "", RT); print RT ";"}' file

alter table HFJ_RES_LINK modify( SRC_PATH varchar2(200) );
create index IDX_VALUESET_EXP_STATUS on TRM_VALUESET(EXPANSION_STATUS);
```

**Details:**

- This `awk` command uses a custom record separator of `SQL` followed by a single space and then followed by a double quoted string.
- Matched text is available in internal variable `RT` to awk.
- When `RT` is non-empty we remove unwanted start `SQL "` and end `"` and all line breaks from `RT` and finally print it with an ending `;`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` can replace your `grep` + `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/.*SQL "([^"]*)".*/\1;/p' log.log
```